# Use WebAPI 2 without OWIN authentication middleware

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, token, owin

I would like to use ASP.NET WebAPI 2, but with my own authentication mechanism. I have tried to remove all the code that comes with SPA template in VS 2013, as well as normal WebAPI template. If I remove all auth-related code from the project and don't configure OWIN in it's Startup.Auth, I always get an error, that OWIN middleware authentication is not setup and I can't get to any controller's action.

What is the correct way to implement a token based authentication in WebAPI 2 with own code, bypassing what's aready is in OWIN host .dll's, including it's requirements of configuration?

Comment: Did you start with a completely blank Web Api 2 template? I don't think there is any OWIN requirements with it and it still uses Global.aspx for the configuration. That said, OWIN is the path Microsoft is heading towards for the future. You should be able to use your own auth even with it including its dlls in the project. This blog series might help some: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: I am it a situation where I need to authenticate users through a provided .net service class. A client for whom we are developing software will not be happy to see OAuth or any bits of it in his pure enterprise oriented solution, so I am aiming for as clean and "under control" solution as possible. Having loads of code hidden and poorly documented (at lease for now) is not a situation that will fit may software projects.

Comment: As for WebAPI 2 template - well, if you create ASP.Net Web Application template project and choose WebAPI in a wizard, you will get the OWIN "burden" with the generated code, unfortunately.

Comment: If you plan to do it all yourself, why not choose the empty asp.net template and then add web api 2 nuget packages?

Comment: @John, I actually did the oposite - taken the web api template and removed all OWIN-stuff via nuget and was free from that point on. You should post it as an answer and I'll mark it as a correct one.

Comment: Ok I added an answer, glad its working for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the blank Asp.Net template and add Web Api 2 as nuget packages, or remove unused stuff from the other starter templates.

Comment: Create the Empty asp.net and add folders and core reference for web api

Answer (score 11):

Similar to John answer but you can remove the OWIN when creating the WebAPI. Much cleaner approach.

To do that:
Select "Change authentication"
[image]

then choose "No Authenciation"

[image]

Now your project wont have the OWIN stuff

Cheers
Choco

Answer (score 1):

You can just comment out the following lines of code:

Startup.cs:

```
//[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Yourpoject.Startup))]

public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    //ConfigureAuth(app);
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
 //// Web API configuration and services
 //// Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
 //config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
 //config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
```